# How do I make changes to the file /etc/gai.conf take effect without a reboot?

Tags: networking, ipv6, ipv4

Per the title, how do I make changes to the file /etc/gai.conf take effect in Ubuntu 20.04 without a reboot? (I altered /etc/gai.conf to force prioritization of 4to6 (IPv4 to IPv6) tunnel traffic over IPv4 traffic, but the change didn't take effect until after a reboot.)

Comment: Try `sudo service networking restart`maybe `sudo service network restart`.

Comment: `kill 1 prozesspid`  sent a SIGHUP(Hangup) `kill -L` gives a little overview.